# CollectionView with a TableView is clipped when rotating screen

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, storyboard, constraints

I have a `CollectionView` with one `item`. This `item` consists of a `tableView` with 1 `cell`. Here is how it looks in Storyboard hierarchy:

[image]

In my `onboardingTableViewCell` I have all displayed to user content: `imageView` and `ShadowView` (UIView).

When device is in a `portrait` mode - everything displayed properly - `ShadowView` bounds equal its `Superview` bounds:

[image]

But when I switch to `landscape` because of the shadow I can see that actually content bounds to `Safe Area` instead of `Superview`:

[image]

I want it to be pinned to `Superview` bounds, so the shadow looks properly.

But all of my constraints in Storyboard are set to `Superview`. `CollectionView` is set in code like that:

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.currentPage, section: 0)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

What is the problem there might be and how can I fix that?

Comment: Do you get any warnings like "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" in the console when you load the screen or rotate it? Another thing that I'd check is the layout ambiguity and the actual effective constraints in the view debugger.

Comment: Hi @VadimBelyaev ! Thank you for the reply. Yep, I noticed the next console warning: `the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values`. It seems the problem was with `collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` as I set it to `.always`. Today's morning I found a way to fix that. Will post an answer later.